# Clang compiler auto-changed strcpy to memmov. macOS

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm-clang, strcpy, memmove

When I compile with `Clang` on macOS (with or without xCode), the call into `strcpy` is auto-substituted to `memmov`.

Is there a `Clang` flag to turn this off?

```
int main(void)
{
    char nice_message[6];
    const char *message = "hello";
    strcpy(nice_message, message);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
clang -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -g -fno-PIE main.c -o foobar
```

**Trace**

```
frida-trace -i "*memmove" -i "*strcpy" -f foobar

Instrumenting functions...                                  

Loaded handler at "/libSystem.B.dylib/_platform_memmove.js"
Loaded handler at "/libSystem.B.dylib/wmemmove.js"
Loaded handler at "/libSystem.B.dylib/_platform_strcpy.js"

Started tracing 3 functions. Press Ctrl+C to stop.                      
           /* TID 0x407 */
     8 ms  _platform_strcpy()
     8 ms     | _platform_memmove()
```

**Update**

I tried the same with `gcc-9` ( installed via `Homebrew` ) and the behavior was largely the same.

**Why do I care?**

I was demonstrating `Stack Overflows` and `Heap Overflows` with `strcpy` and the differences between:

[image]

Comment: And the problem with it is ...?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers recognize certain functions and automatically expand them inline.  For GCC and Clang, you can disable this behavior by compiling without optimization (`-O0`), switching to freestanding mode (`-ffreestanding`, as opposed to hosted), or by disabling built-in expansions (`-fno-builtin`).

Comment: Thanks @Florian.  I tried your recommendation. I ended ( with no success ) with this:    `clang -O0 -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -fno-sanitize=cfi -fno-sanitize=safe-stack -fno-PIE -Wno-format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 heap.c -o hitme`.

Comment: Interestingly, when `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` is specified, the Symbol inside the binary is `__strcpy_chk`.  when `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` it is normal `strcpy`.   `__strcpy_chk` appears to check for Buffer Overflows.